# VSTS to AzureRM deployment issue - 403 forbidden

Tags: azure

I'm having issues with a new Azure subscription and specifically deploying to it from my VSTS subscription. I was refused when I tried to automatically create the AzureRM Service Principal (also Forbidden), but going through the manual steps seemed to work, but there's something off still.

```
2016-11-15T18:22:52.7297058Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy AzureRM App Service: {appname}2016-11-15T18:22:52.7876996Z 
==============================================================================
2016-11-15T18:22:52.7876996Z Task         : Azure App Service Deploy
2016-11-15T18:22:52.7876996Z Description  : Update Azure App Service using Web Deploy / Kudu REST APIs
2016-11-15T18:22:52.7876996Z Version      : 2.1.4
2016-11-15T18:22:52.7876996Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2016-11-15T18:22:52.7876996Z Help         : [More Information](https://aka.ms/azurermwebdeployreadme)
2016-11-15T18:22:52.7876996Z ==============================================================================
2016-11-15T18:22:54.4056999Z {guid} exists true
2016-11-15T18:22:55.1131939Z ##[error]Forbidden
2016-11-15T18:22:55.1141941Z ##[error]Unable to retrieve connectiondetails for azureRM WebApp : {appname}. Status Code: 403 (Forbidden)
2016-11-15T18:22:55.1271939Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy AzureRM App Service: {appname}
```

(I've obscured the app name and one GUID in there because I'm not sure if that's secure to share - if that's an important detail, let me know.)

I don't know what resource is forbidden, what forbids it, or what credentials I need to have to get this right. AzureRM is all kind of a black box - I've searched on this error and found only the GitHub repository for the code that generates it.

Classic deployment works OK, but I see that's deprecated so I'd rather not fall back to that.

Comment: are you sure you have the appropriate permissions?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? My release worked fine a few times then stopped with this error.

Comment: As I remember it, we got past this by giving my users more access than we thought was really necessary.